# Vue js - How to use props in data and methods

Tags: vue.js

I am new in vue js , I am passing data from parent component to child one using props and I can use it in child normally but I can't use it in data of child component

parent

```
<template>
    <div>
        <show-question :qdata="question" v-if="question"></show-question>
        <h1 v-if="!question"> some error </h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import ShowQuestion from './ShowQuestion';

export default {
    created(){
        axios.get(`/api/question/${this.$route.params.slug}`)
        .then(res => {
            this.question = res.data.data
            })
    },

    data(){
        return {
            question : {},
        }
    },

    components:{
        ShowQuestion,
    },
}
</script>
```

child

```
<template>
    <v-container>
        <v-card>
            <div>
                <v-card-title class="blue--text"
                    >{{ data.title }}
                    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                    <v-btn color="teal white--text">5 Replies</v-btn>
                </v-card-title>
                <v-card-subtitle
                    > {{data.uid}} {{ data.user }} said {{ data.created_at }}</v-card-subtitle
                >
            </div>
            <v-card-text>{{ data.body }}</v-card-text>

            <v-card-actions v-if="own">
                <v-btn icon text>
                    <v-icon color="orange">create</v-icon>
                </v-btn>

                <v-btn icon text>
                    <v-icon color="red">delete</v-icon>
                </v-btn>

            </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['qdata'],
    data(){
        return {
            own: User.own(this.qdata.uid),
        };
    },
};
</script>
```

this.qdata.uid is always be undefined in console, although it supposed it have values and I can saw it from child template

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vB6fh.png)

Comment: how about `this.qdata` is it also undefined?

Comment: did you also check `this.$props`?

Comment: yes I also checked it, but I know my mistake by helping from @Shoejep , child mounted early

Answer (score 1):

Your `show-question`component is mounted early on because `v-if="question"` is true. When `show-question` is mounted, your api call hasn't had a chance to finish, so `question` is the same as the initial value `{}`, which is why `uid` is undefined.

I would change `question : {}` to `question: null`, then the child component will only be mounted when there's a `question` (after the api call).

Answer (score 0):

This is simply because if you check the **truthy** of an object it will always return `true` even if the object is empty, which results in the component being rendered before the API call has finished.

Instead, you can check if it's empty or not by converting it to an array and check it's length value, i.e. `Object.entries(question).length` or simply use the lodash helper method: `_isEmpty(question)`.

Also a quick side note: it's cleaner to use `v-else` after `v-if` when you want to render something **or** the other instead of explicitly negating the value in another `v-if`, though they're required to be direct siblings.